# understanding the regular expression in python

Tags: python

I am learning re in python.
I understand all other things in the following example.
but, i really dont understand what special (in tags) means in the following example.

```
re.compile('((?P<special>[0:-])\s)')
```

kindly help if know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're called named capturing groups.

A quick explanation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

> Python's regex module was the first to offer a solution: named
>   capture. By assigning a name to a capturing group, you can easily
>   reference it by name. (?P<name>group) captures the match of group into
>   the backreference "name". You can reference the contents of the group
>   with the numbered backreference \1 or the named backreference
>   (?P=name).

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Named Capture Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).